# How to set the type for a variable I post to a Sprint REST API?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I couldn't think of a good title for this question, my apologies. I hope my explanation clears things ups.

I've started using Spring yesterday. I'm currently trying to do something that probably has been asked before, but English isn't my first language and I can't find the right words to Google my answer. If you can refer me to a question where this has been asked before that would be great too.

The idea is that someone can POST information to the REST API I made with Spring, but the data type of the accompanying value(s) can be a string, boolean or number/integer. The JSON I post looks like this at the moment:

```
{
  "values": [
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "type": "number",
            "value": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "zone",
            "type": "string",
            "value": "Test String"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have set up two models, one "main" model which currently holds an array of Value classes. The Value classes hold the information of each value from the "values" array in the JSON:

```
public class HeadComponent {
    //This class will get some other fields later

    public Value[] values;

    public HeadComponent() {

    }
}

public class Value {
    public String name, type, value;

    public Value() {
    }
}
```

When I return the object via a route every value gets converted to a String, which isn't surprising of course, considering I made every field a String in the model.

```
{  
   "values":[  
      {  
         "name":"temp",
         "type":"number",
         "value":"25"
      },
      {  
         "name":"zone",
         "type":"string",
         "value":"Test String"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle different types within one model. Should I keep my Value class this way and manually try converting the values in the back-end? Does Spring happen to have a feature which allows me to have multiple types for a variable? Or do you have any other things I can look into?

I hope this wasn't too confusing, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could map the whole request to something like `Map<String, Object>` and then parse them individually from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and sorry for my late reaction)! I went to bed and I thought of something similar. I secretly hoped for something easier, but this works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't have to manage types yourself, the conversion is done automatically by the Spring Message converter. Try changing the type of your 'value' ( an int for example) variable and you will that will work

Comment: You mean in the model? That does work, but an user can also send strings and booleans to my API and I preferably don't want to create an 'intValue' and 'stringValue' (or something similar) in the JSON and just use the 'value' field for multiple types.